# Coinbase custom pay button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bitcoin

I would like to make my own custom Coinbase payment button and have the following code which is just a copy paste of ["Using Your Own Button And Custom Javascript Events"](https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/payment_buttons) example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <a href='#' class='my-custom-link'>Show Me The Modal!</a>

    <div class="coinbase-button" data-code="4d4b84bbad4508b64b61d372ea394dad" data-button-style="none"></div><script src="https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.my-custom-link').click(function(){
          $(document).trigger('coinbase_show_modal', '4d4b84bbad4508b64b61d372ea394dad');
          return false;
        });

        $(document).on('coinbase_payment_complete', function(event, code){
          console.log("Payment completed for button "+code);
          window.location = "/confirmation.html";
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However it does not work. Any ideas why?

'Show Me The Modal!' link is displayed. The `$('.my-custom-link').click()` function is called. Using Google Chrome I can see that an iframe is loaded with what I assume is the modal dialog code containing payment instructions. However nothing happens when I click on the 'Show Me The Modal!' link.

Comment: Could you check the console? Let me know if you find any errors.

Comment: No errors what so ever which is why I don't have anything to go on. I am using Chrome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code isn't working because coinbase.com blocks custom buttons from working after triggering them with custom scripts too much

Ask a friend to test your code, it should work for other people.

I'm having the same issue. Deleting browser cookies, cache, flash cookies, changing IP doesn't work. I guess the only solutions are:

> 1. wait for the ban from coinbase.com to expire
> 2. [contact support](http://support.coinbase.com) about it
> 3. don't do anything, it's working, but not for you

**Update:**
A working solution/hack that I found was using the default button, hiding it with **opacity: 0;** and putting it on top of your custom button. That way you can make it look like the user is clicking the custom button, when in fact, he's clicking the hidden default button (which works).

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uaMdX/show 
Code demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uaMdX/

```
<a href='#' class='my-custom-link'>Show Me The Modal!</a>

<div class="coinbase-button" data-code="4d4b84bbad4508b64b61d372ea394dad" data-button-style="small"></div>

<script src="https://coinbase.com/assets/button.js"></script>

<style>
#coinbase_button_iframe_4d4b84bbad4508b64b61d372ea394dad {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 140px!important;
    height: 18px!important;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    /*
    debugging_code: uncomment_to_show_the_button;
    opacity: 0.5;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    */
}

</style>
```

*If your needs are more specific you should use jQuery to dynamically add the styles/position the iframe for the hidden button.

Comment: I tried on a different computer which was on a different network with no success so I left a message with support. The Coinbase Disqus support forum did not seem to work as I tried leaving a couple of messages but they just got deleted.

Comment: Strange, using an IP from another country worked for me. I also updated my answer with a working (temporary) hack.

Comment: Great hack. This works for me also. I'll mark it as correct but I'll wait for coinbase to get back to me with their explanation (assuming they do). The only difficulty is I wonder if 'coinbase_payment_complete' will still be triggered.

Comment: I just tried my original example and it seems to work on jsFiddle now. So maybe it has something to do with running the script on localhost. I'll investigate and get back to this thread.

Comment: Nope, it's just that the temporary ban from coinbase expired for you. If they don't fix the problem you'll get banned again if you trigger it too often. Another thing that proves this idea is that I still can't run your code even on jsFiddle, because my ban hasn't expired yet. (I got banned yesterday)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved it. I tried it out with your code and it does not work as you said. I took the time to modify it a little bit and it works now. http://pastie.org/8687468 Please let me know if what I fixed was intended.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately the pasted code also shows the default Coinbase pay now button as well as the link. `data-button-style="none"` is needed to hide the default button. When I add `data-button-style="none"` the link still does not work.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is customize the button? Basically when you press "show me the modal", you want it to open the payment modal?

Answer (score -1):

Try creating another page, and put only what coinbase gives you. If that works then it is probably a Issue on your side. If not, let me know.

Comment: The HTML in the question was an exact copy/paste of https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/payment_buttons 'Using Your Own Button And Custom Javascript Events'. I needed to add the link to JQuery so the example would work. I have also experimented with different data-code values with no success. Does it work for you?

Comment: For me, it works. Here is the code I used. http://pastie.org/8686577 The css is a little bit messed up on my computer, but it works... It might be some of your Javascript that is messing with your code.

Comment: @nahtnam He said he wanted a custom button, your code is the default button.